# Why the cubic root of negative number returns a complex value only?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, complex

I am trying to evaluate the cubic root of a negative number

$(5 (7 - 3 \sqrt{6}))^{1/3}$

by

```
(5 (7 - 3 Sqrt[6]))^(1/3) // N
```

which returns only:

> 0.601656 + 1.0421 i

but

```
NSolve[5 (7 - 3 Sqrt[6]) == x^3, x]
```

returns:

> {{x -> -1.20331}, {x -> 0.601656 - 1.0421 i}, {x -> 
>      0.601656 + 1.0421 i}}

Why does Mathematica not return the real root as default?

Comment: That would be because, by convention, the principal cube root is defined as a complex number with positive imaginary part, which is what Mathematica returns. If you want the real solution, you can use Mathematica's `CubeRoot` function.

Comment: Expanding on @Pirx 's comment, `N` will return the root that has the lowest angle when it is expressed in polar ($re^{i \theta}$) form.

Comment: Thank you! `CubeRoot` might be my choice for this case. Is there any built-in-function for 1/5, 1/7 power of negative numbers similar to CubeRoot for cubic root?

Comment: That would be `Surd`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for kind guidance!